# ¿Transicion fade a la imagen de fondo?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Llevo un buen rato dandole vueltas a mi problema y no consigo solucionar nada. Resulta que tengo una serie de fondos que quiero ir alternando cada X segundos. La imagen principal la asigno en el css:

```
body#pag-index {
    background-image: url(../imgs/fondo.jpg);
}
```

Mientras que el código JavaScript que estoy usando para alternar las imagenes es este:

```
var imagenes = ["fondo.jpg", "fondo2.jpg", "fondo3.jpg"];
var numImagen = 1;

setInterval(function(){
  var imgActual = imagenes[numImagen];
  var dir = "imgs/"+imgActual;
  $("#pag-index").css("backgroundImage", "url(" + dir + ")");
  if(numImagen + 1 == imagenes.length){
    numImagen = 0;
  } else {
    numImagen++;
  }

} ,5000);
```

Lo tengo puesto de esta manera para que se vayan alternando las imagenes en orden cada 5 segundos, y cuando llegue al final de la lista, que se vuelvan a repetir. Esta parte me funciona, pero lo que ya no me funciona y estoy intentando conseguir, es ese cambio de imagen con un `fadeOut` para la imagen actual y un `fadeIn` para la imagen siguiente.

Alguna idea?

Comment: No veo donde intentas usar las transiciones fadeIn y fadeOut de jQuery, porfavor edita la pregunta y pon la parte donde las intentas usar, ademas recuerda que la propiedad backroundImage de css no es animable.

Comment: La intento usar dentro del setInterval, no pongo como la estoy usando por que he probado de varias formas y todas me dan error. Pero generalmente he intentando usarlo dentro del setInterval. Se que no hay una única manera de hacer las cosas, se te ocurre como meter el ese código el fade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías hacerlo de varias formas. Yo recomiendo hacerlo mediante css, queda bastante mejor la animación. De esta forma únicamente tendrías que añadir transition: background 1s linear; al contenedor donde está cambiando el background y no tendrías que cambiar tu código. 
No obstante, si aun así lo quieres hacer por jquery, tendrías que hacer la sustitución del background dentro del callback del fadeTo.

Te adjunto un codesnippet par que lo veas en acción (ojo porque he adaptado el dir par que funcione con mi ejemplo)

```js
var numImagen = 0;
var imagenes = [
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/361',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/362',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/363',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/364',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/365',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/366',
  'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/367',
  
]
setInterval(function(){
  var imgActual = imagenes[numImagen];
  var dir = imgActual;
  $("#pag-index").css("backgroundImage", "url(" + dir + ")");

  if(numImagen + 1 == imagenes.length){
    numImagen = 0;
  } else {
    numImagen++;
  }

} ,2000);
```

```css
#pag-index {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: 'https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360';
  transition: background 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="pag-index"></div>
```

La forma de hacerlo en JQuery sería:

```
  $('#pag-index').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + dir + ')');
  }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, de verdad! Usé el código del css, da mucha rabia que tan solo fuera una línea lo que había que añadir... No encontré esa referencia por ningún sitio. Me has ayudado muchisimo!